# password is not hashed and saved in the database

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, bcrypt, password-encryption

i used library bcryptjs for registration system. bcryptjs is working and hashing the password. but it not save the hashed password in the mongo db.

**UserSchema**

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        match: [/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/,]
    },
    password: String
})

UserSchema.methods.generateJwtFromUser = function(){
    const { JWT_SECRET_KEY, JWT_EXPIRE } = process.env;
    const payload = {
        id: this._id,
        name: this.name
    }
    const token = jwt.sign(payload, JWT_SECRET_KEY, {
        expiresIn: JWT_EXPIRE
    })

    return token;
}

UserSchema.pre("save", function(next){
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err,salt) => {
        if(err) next(err);
        bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt, (err,hash) => {
            if(err) next(err);
            this.password = hash;
            next();
        })
    })
    next();
})
```

**register controller**

```
const register = asyncErrorWrapper(async (req,res) => {
    const infos = req.body;

    const user = await User.create({
        ...infos
    });

    sendJwtToClient(user, res);
})
```

**sendJwtToClient function**

```
const sendJwtToClient = (user,res) => {
   const token = user.generateJwtFromUser();

   return res.status(200).json({ 
        success: true,
   })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong in your *"UserSchema"* I didn't see any password option for storing the password into the database.

You can try with this:

```
UserSchema.methods.generateJwtFromUser = function(){
    const { JWT_SECRET_KEY, JWT_EXPIRE } = process.env;
    const payload = {
        id: this._id,
        name: this.name,
        password: this.password

    }
    const token = jwt.sign(payload, JWT_SECRET_KEY, {
        expiresIn: JWT_EXPIRE
    })

    return token;
}

UserSchema.pre("save", function(next){
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err,salt) => {
        if(err) next(err);
        bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt, (err,hash) => {
            if(err) next(err);
            this.password = hash;
            next();
        })
    })
    next();
})
```

Comment: actually that function used to generate tokens, not to save in database